Field tensor for monochromatic EM wave
I’m having some troubles computing $F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$ for a 4-potential $A^\mu(x) = \overline{A}^\mu \exp\left(-ik_\alpha x^\alpha\right)$, that is derived under the assumptions $\partial_\mu A^\mu=0$ and $\partial_\mu\partial^\mu A^\nu=0$, with constants $\overline{A}^\mu$ complex and $k^\mu$ real.
I know it must equal $0$, but it seems I can’t find a way to derive it using $k_\mu A^\mu(x)= k_\mu A^{*\mu}(x)=0 $ (obtained by inserting $A^\mu(x)$ in the Lorenz gauge condition).
I think my main problem is having to deal with the real part of the 4-potential, which I tried to solve by using $$\Re\{A^\mu\}=\frac{1}{2} (A^\mu +(A^*)^\mu),$$ but it only complicated the computation without bringing me to the correct result.
I’m still a newbie with covariant formalism, so if you could help me with some hints on how to approach both $F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu\nu}$ and $F^{\mu\nu}F^{\rho}_\nu$, it would be amazing.
EDIT: I eventually found a way to solve it which is fairly easy. It easy to prove that:
$$
\begin{align}
F^{\mu\nu} &= \Re\{\partial^\mu A^\nu - \partial^\nu A^\mu\} = \Re\{i k^\nu A^\mu - i k^\mu A^\nu\} = \Im\{k^\mu A^\nu - k^\nu A^\mu\} \\
&= k^\mu \Im\{A^\nu\} - k^\nu \Im\{A^\mu\}\equiv k^\mu \tilde{A}^\nu - k^\nu \tilde{A}^\mu
\end{align}
$$
Using this notation for the imaginary of the 4-potential $\tilde{A}^\mu = \Im\{A^\mu\}$:
$$
F^{\mu\nu} F_{\mu\nu} = (k^\mu \tilde{A}^\nu - k^\nu \tilde{A}^\mu)(k_\mu \tilde{A}_\nu - k_\nu \tilde{A}_\mu)
$$
Now it is possibile to distribute the product without worrying about real or imaginary parts and it is possible to easily use the conditions $k^\mu k_\mu =0, \ k_\mu A^\mu = k_\mu (A^*)^\mu = 0$.
The same considerations can be used to compute $F^{\mu\nu}F^\rho_\nu$ and find that its mean over a period is:
$$
\langle F^{\mu\nu}F^\rho_\nu\rangle=\frac{k^\mu k^\rho}{2}\langle A^\nu \tilde{A}_\nu \rangle
$$
NOTE: This allows to obtain the impulse-energy tensor in the case of a plane monochromatic electromagnetic wave.

Why not take the real part after you compute a complex $F$?

@Craig Because if I ignore the real part and do the calculation, then I would be taking the real part of the whole product, instead of taking the product of the real part, which (if I’m not mistaken) is not the same thing. In other words, what I’m saying is that: $\Re{F^{\alpha\beta} F_{\alpha\beta}}\neq\Re{F^{\alpha\beta}}\Re{F_{\alpha\beta}}$.
